# -Adding a column to a pandas dataframe that is sum of 3 different rows in another column AND slides those rows down like in excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

```
   a  b  c  
0  1  2  3 
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
3 10 11 12
4 13 14 15
5 16 17 18 
6 19 20 21
7 22 23 24
8 25 26 27
```

I'd like to add a column `d` that is the sum of column A row 0, column A row 2, and column A row 5.

I figured out how to do:

```
df['d']=df.loc[0,'a'] + df.loc[2,'a'] + df.loc[5,'a']
```

But the result is a static d tied to only those rows. I'd like a dynamic d, such that column d, row 2 is the sum of column a, row 1, column a, row3, and column a, row 6.

The end result should be:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3 24
1  4  5  6 33
2  7  8  9 42
3 10 11 12 ---And so on
4 13 14 15 ---
5 16 17 18 --- 
6 19 20 21 ---
7 22 23 24 ---
8 25 26 27 ---
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is `shift`

```
df.a+df.a.shift(-2)+df.a.shift(-5)
Out[412]: 
0    24.0
1    33.0
2    42.0
3    51.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64

df['d']=df.a+df.a.shift(-2)+df.a.shift(-5)
df
Out[414]: 
    a   b   c     d
0   1   2   3  24.0
1   4   5   6  33.0
2   7   8   9  42.0
3  10  11  12  51.0
4  13  14  15   NaN
5  16  17  18   NaN
6  19  20  21   NaN
7  22  23  24   NaN
8  25  26  27   NaN
```